# Do the IE developer tools get installed with every IE 8 now?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-8

I've just been around a bunch of machines in our office and they all appear to have the IE Developer toolbar installed.  This doesn't make sense for a lot of them.  No-one appears to consciously remember loading it.  I'm wondering if Microsoft pushed it along with a windows update at some point?

This is a development shop so having some machines with it makes sense.  My own machine I know I've installed it on for example.  I'm just struggling to find a machine without it to do some testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing new about that. It has been part of IE8 [since day 1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/internet-explorer-8-beta-1-for-developers-now-available), replacing the separate Developer Toolbar they had for IE6 and IE7.

Consequently, you *can't* find a machine with IE8, but without the developer tools; it's no longer something that's installed separately.

Comment: Well that explains a thing or two!  Now all I need to do is ask some questions about default rendering mode.

Comment: @Colin: The IE team has a complete flow chart on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/02/how-ie8-determines-document-mode.aspx for that.